# Qt - Static build for open source/commercial

Tags: c++, qt

Simple question, i wanted to know that is it legal to build a static application for an open source program in Qt? I heard that it's against the Qt rules.

Also, if I want to do a static build for commercial, it requires a license file which i have to purchase obviously. So isn't there any other way to build statically without any problems or anything?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352896/qt-commercial-licenses

Answer (score 0):

From [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/):

> Qt can be used under open source (LGPL v2.1) or commercial terms.

You can find LGPL v2.1 [at opensource.org](http://opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php), or read about it [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) (among many other places).

Nobody's going to give you actual legal advice except a lawyer under contract to you (and if anyone does, you shouldn't take it).

I think it's fair to say that most developers would agree that:

- LGPL does not allow static linking, except in LGPL, GPL, or compatible free software projects.
- If you do static link it, this may make your software LGPL too.
- That was the FSF's intention in writing it, and presumably the intention of most people who use it as a license.
- Even if it's not illegal to statically-link LGPL code into commercial code, it's probably unethical.
- Even if you don't care about legality or ethics, it could lead to serious PR problems.

So, I personally wouldn't do it. But that's just me, not legal advice.

As for the commercial license, yes, you have pay for that. Go to [the commercial Qt site](http://qt.digia.com/en/) to find out more.

Comment: So you mean I can't do a static release for open source?

Comment: Depends what you mean by open source. If your license is an LGPL-compatible free software license, you probably can, but doing so may change your license to LGPL whether you want it to or not. If it's not compatible, you probably can't at all. Plus, if you say "open source" instead of "free" to rms, his head will explode. Again, not legal advice, and you shouldn't take it as such. At any rate, SO is probably not the place to go for free/open source license information.

Comment: Suppose I made an application (for example windows based) which is totally free for use, but I partnered up with someone who says that they will pay me let's say $0.5 per installation of my software using their installation file. So can I do a static release for open source for this kind of purpose?

Comment: If your program is going to be GPL or LGPL, that should be fine. Your partner is allowed to sell your GPL program, as long as they follow the rules. (That means, e.g., your program can't be under their EULA; they have to tell people where to get your source; etc.) Also, "free for use" (if you mean "no cost") is pretty much irrelevant to (L)GPL; as long as people are free (in the other sense) to copy, modify, and distribute your code, that's what matters.

Comment: I'm facing a problem. When I do a static release compile for open source, it shows vmr9.h not found dshow.h not found and many more.. :/ man this thing is so complicated! What do I do??

Comment: That's a completely different problem; open a new question for that.